# How to change HIVE field delimeter when using Sqoop Imprt-all-tables command

Tags: mysql, hive, sqoop

I am trying to run the following command to import all tables in a mysql database.

```
 sqoop import-all-tables \
  --num-mappers 4 \
  --connect "jdbc:mysql://<host>:<port>/SomeDB" \
  --username=SomeUser \
  --password=SomePassword \
  --hive-import \
  --hive-overwrite \
  --create-hive-table \
  --hive-database STAGING_AREA
```

This is creating tables with following delimiters

```
Storage Desc Params:         
    field.delim             \u0001              
    line.delim              \n                  
    serialization.format    \u0001
```

How do i change the field delimiter to say '|' when running the above sqoop command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following to the sqoop option list

```
--fields-terminated-by \
```

and that solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
chown sqoop:sqoop /var/lib/sqoop 
chmod 755 /var/lib/sqoop
```

But your problem may not be this. You can look Job History Server Web UI for detailed logs.